# Why can't I connect to the internet on my iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone, internet, apple-id

I've just bought an iPhone 4 and I want to connect to the internet but I can't do so.

Do I need an apple id to use an iPhone?

Definitely I've contacted my dataplan service and they are saying I should be able to connect to the internet now. But i can't!

I've waited over 3 weeks but still no internet. These are the messages i get from 1627:

> May 8, 2011 5:33 PM
>
> Dear Valued Customer, your GSM Mi
>   World Mobile service has been
>   activated as requested.
>
> Dear Valued Customer, your GSM Mi
>   World Mobile service has been
>   activated as requested.
>
> May 16, 2011 1:08 PM
>
> Thank you for re-contracting your M1
>   line with IPHONE 4, 16GB, WHITE.
>   Please call us at 1627 immediately if
>   you did not subscribe to M1
>   service(s).

I'm thinking there's something I need to do in settings but I don't know what.. Right now if i open safari it just won't connect.

Comment: No you don't need an Apple ID.
What's the problem connecting to Internet? Are you on a Wi-Fi network?

Comment: nop im trying to connect using 3gs

Comment: To connect to some mobile networks you need to configure your phone correctly. Usual procedure is, the provider send you a SMS with the config. data. You will have to open it and the correct settings will saved under network settings. I am not sure if that's the case with you. If you didn't get an SMS they can send it again at your request.

Comment: i've updated the question with more info

Comment: guys my problem is solved

Comment: Pacerier, how you solve your problem? I encountered same problem on iphone4s M1, can you post your solution?

Comment: @xue I forgot, I think I just kept waiting for another few weeks and it got solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No - you only need a correctly provisioned data plan and working iPhone software. There isn't much that you can mis-configure unless you jailbreak or start mucking with [custom iPhone carrier settings profiles](http://www.macworld.com/article/143088/2009/10/carriersettings.html).

iPhone data can break or be misconfigured on the carrier end - even if SMS and voice calls work, there can still be a problem with the data service so you may need to get help from your carrier that is providing your data access. It could also be a software issue and Apple is the best place to get that sorted.

Your question is basically how do I systematically troubleshoot iPhone data and/or teach myself how to operate my new phone. (no offense, but it's hard to determine from a one sentence question what your level of comfort is with iPhone data terms and how it may break.)

You might want to get some help from Apple or the carrier since the internet works as long as you are in working Wifi or your data plan is active on the iPhone. Troubleshooting an issue by back and forth on a discussion board is very hard so it's best to get real-time assistance when you are sitting in front of your computer to update the software if needed.

http://www.apple.com/support/iphone/ has some great getting started tips if you want to work through it yourself.

Specifically http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1976 documents the concepts and has an express lane link to get support directly from Apple to narrow down the cause - if 3G is showing in the menu bar it's not some obvious error or switch but something obscure or a carrier issue.

Comment: ok my data plan is active. i can sms / make calls etc. Im not trying to connect using wifi. i'm trying to connect using 3gs, how may i do it?

Comment: sms travels over a command channel unused by voice, voice can be active and data not provisioned. Have you informed  your carrier that data you are paying for isn't working and have their tech verify that dataplan is actually active on their wireless network for your SIM?

Comment: yes i've called them and they say that its active. But i still can't connect!

Comment: Then you can strike that off the list. Hang in there - you'll know how these things work before long. Next up is getting help from Apple in person or over the internet to work through the potential device issues. Good Luck!

Comment: @bmike i've updated the question with more info

Comment: Three weeks of patience! You must be a saint. In the settings app, what are the following values? Version, carrier, modem firmware. Have you connected to iTunes and updated the iPhone software? Also enter field test mode by calling \*3001#12345#\* - I'm curious what PDP Context List - 0 - lists. You should have an ip address, PDP Type of "IP" and access point name iPhone

Comment: @bmike my carrier is SGP-M1-3GSM. I don't know about the version / modem firmware (where is it shown?). I've connected to ITunes to put some songs in but I don't know if i did (or how to) update the iphone software. When i call 3001#12345# i get "Error performing request No Network Service"

Answer (score 1):

If its still not work, go to General > Reset all setting :) It works for me :)

Answer (score 1):

To access the internet you need 2 things

1. Active Carrier Data Plan
2. The configuration options for that carrier

This is usually uploaded from iTunes when the handset is activated or direct from the carrier. In the absence of this you can configure them yourself however you need to get the correct settings.  On the iPhone go to

Settings > General > Network

On here ensure your settings have enabled 3G and Cellular Data

Now go into Cellular Data Network and enter the correct APN configurations

*A quick google has found these for your M1 carrier which may or may not be correct ([Link](http://apt.if0rce.com/carriers/countries/sg/M1.html) )*

- APN: miworld
- Username: 65(mobile number)
- Password: user123

You probably dont have visual voicemail so ignore this, and I can't see any mention of the correct MMS APN so you will need to find that or ignore it also.

Answer (score -1):

I highly suggest you start with the [iPhone User Guide](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/iPhone_iOS3.1_User_Guide.pdf) and go through activation and configuration. To connect to the internet you need either a WiFi or 3G connection.

Comment: i actually wanted to read it. But you see its over 200 pages and I'd take more than 1 entire day to finish it

Comment: i do know that i need a wifi or 3g connection..

Comment: Have you tried the same SIM in a friends phone where the internet usually works? Worth a try.

Comment: i've updated the question with more info